# Wrong keyboard layout when using mobaxterm x11 forwarding

Tags: centos, centos7, x11-forwarding, mobaxterm

I am using MobaXTerm to connect to a remote machine and thus uses its x11 forwarding to use graphic applications.

However, despite the fact that all my locales are well set (France),all the application used with the X server are using a qwerty layout.

Comment: X11 has a special locale setting in MobaXterm: Settings -> Configuration -> X11 -> Keyboard.

Comment: Yes, but modifying it does not change anything, whatever the language it stays in qwerty

Comment: I fixed the problem by 1°)moving moba home and slash to my folder C:\Dev.
2°) In settings/general, configure "persistent home directory" and "persistent root directory" accordingly.
If it doesn't work, with the pro version, you can try this solution after putting the portable version in C:\Dev and configure both portable and pro version the same way..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my personal case, switching to the pro version fixed the issue.

However I also successfully fixed this issue by changing the 'X11 server display mode' setting, see screenshot;

['X11 server display mode' setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF5lb.png)